# Proving absolute integral inequality

Tags: indefinite-integrals

> I have a function $f(x)$ in $[0,2\pi]$ for which $f(0) = f(2\pi)$ and for which $|f''(x)| \le 1$. Show that $$\left|\int_0^{2\pi} f(t)\sin(nt)dt\right| \le \frac{4}{n^2}$$
>   for every natural $n$.

How do I prove this? I manage to get to the integral using the substitution method twice but I can't get the inequality.

Thanks

Comment: Yes, It's okay, thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For any positive integer $n$, by integration by parts,
\begin{align*}\int_0^{2\pi} f(t)\sin(nt)dt&=\left[\frac{-f(t)\cos(nt)}{n}\right]_0^{2\pi}+\frac{1}{n}\int_0^{2\pi} f'(t)\cos(nt)dt\\&=\left[\frac{f'(t)\sin(nt)}{n^2}\right]_0^{2\pi}-\frac{1}{n^2}\int_0^{2\pi} f''(t)\sin(nt)dt\\
&=-\frac{1}{n^2}\int_0^{2\pi} f''(t)\sin(nt)dt.
\end{align*}
Hence, by $|f''(x)|\leq 1$, it follows
$$\left|\int_0^{2\pi} f(t)\sin(nt)dt\right| \leq \frac{1}{n^2}\int_0^{2\pi} |\sin(nt)|dt.$$
Can you take it from here?

Comment: Thanks @Robert Z,
I've managed to get to this myself but my problem is how to use the |f''x| <=1 thing correctly to get this inequality..I've tried but I can't get the 4/n^2 
I've tried using Triangle Inequality with Absolute Value but I don't think I'm doing it right.

Comment: @Jamaico Note that the remaining integral is $2n\int_0^{\pi/n} \sin(nt)dt$.

Comment: Thank you very much @Robert Z